# Aspnetboilerplate ObjectMapper or Logger is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, aspnetboilerplate

I have a small assembly that utilises the following NuGet packages Abp, Abp.AspNetCore and Abp.AbpAutoMapper.

For reference I am using Abp 6.4.0

I have added the depends to the module, the main service is also below.

The constructor inject is valid for both IObjectMapper and Ilogger. Whereas the inherited DomainService and ApplicationService for ObjectMapper and Logger are always null / NullLogger.Instance or NullObjectMapper.Instance.

```
[DependsOn(typeof(AbpAutoMapperModule))]
public class ServiceModule:AbpModule {
  
   // other methods and logic
  
   public override void PostInitialize(){
      var mainService = Configuration.Get<IMainService>();
      Task.Run(() =>
      {
          mainService.Start();
      });
      base.PostInitialize();
   }
}


public class MainService : ApplicationService, IMainService
{
    public MainService(IObjectMapper mapper, ILogger logger)
    {
       if (Logger == NullLogger.Instance)
       {
          Debug.WriteLine("No logger configured.....");
       }

       if (ObjectMapper == NullObjectMapper.Instance)
       {
          Debug.WriteLine("No mapper configured.....");
       }
     }
 }

 // OR domain service

 public class MainService : DomainService, IMainService
 {
     public MainService(IObjectMapper mapper, ILogger logger)
     {
        if (Logger == NullLogger.Instance)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("No logger configured.....");
        }

        if (ObjectMapper == NullObjectMapper.Instance)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("No mapper configured.....");
        }
     }
 }
```

Any ideas on how this can be resolved?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think, u have to register your injections. Something like this:

```
public class ServiceModule:AbpModule {
  
   // other methods and logic

   public override void ConfigureServices(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
   {
       context.Services.AddScoped<IMainService>(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<MainService>());
   }
  
   public override void PostInitialize(){
      var mainService = Configuration.Get<IMainService>();
      Task.Run(() =>
      {
          mainService.Start();
      });
      base.PostInitialize();
   }
}
```

Comment: This uses Volo.Abp.Core package, which i am hesitant to use as its a LGPL license compared to MIT.

Answer (score 0):

`DomainService` and `ApplicationService` allow `IObjectMapper` and `ILogger` to be property-injected.

If `MainService` requires non-[null object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern) instances to work properly, you can proactively assign your constructor-injected instances:

```cs
public MainService(IObjectMapper mapper, ILogger logger)
{
    ObjectMapper = mapper;
    Logger = logger;
}
```

References:

- https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Dependency-Injection#property-injection-pattern
- https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Logging#getting-the-logger